# C# Asp.net query an HTML formatted string without the html tags exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

very basic question but i can't seen to solve my issue.
I am querying my database which contains HTML formatted strings but i want to query **only** the text so i though to remove the HTML tags with Regex and do a contains on it but fails with the following error message `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Replace(System.String, System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`
Here is my code

```
                queryString = queryString.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                flagedIssues =
                    flagedIssues.Where(
                        i =>
                            Regex.Replace(i.Description, "<.*?>", string.Empty).Contains(queryString) ||
                            i.IssueTagses.Any(t => t.Tag.Contains(queryString)) ||
                            i.Category.Description.Contains(queryString));
            }
```

Any idea how i can resolve this error and get only the text from my Description?

**UPDATE** **1**

So i have tried with the HTML Agility pack as suggested added the code to reflect this bellow but get a new error message saying my function is not recognised by LINQ Mabye this wasnt obvious in my first question but the error comes when i try to convert this into an IEnumerable and return it as LINQ can't run either Regex.Replace or my method

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryString))
            {
                queryString = queryString.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
                flagedIssues =
                    flagedIssues.Where(
                        i =>
                            CleanHtml(i.Description).Contains(queryString) ||
                            i.IssueTagses.Any(t => t.Tag.Contains(queryString)) ||
                            i.Category.Description.Contains(queryString));
            }
 private string CleanHtml(string dirtyString)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(dirtyString);
        return doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be using Regex in the following context:

```
return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
```

Then you can check if the returned string contains whatever you're searching for.

Keep in mind this isn't the best solution as it does not cover all of the cases for HTML tags.
Consider using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) as a better solution.

Comment: Quick question how can i implement this with the return statement and still use the Where clause as i cant seem to fit this with the context i want.

Comment: Why would you want to use the Where clause in the first place? Your returned statement is a string which is not an Enumerable object type - therefore you can't use the Where clause on it.